# will this approach work for executing ddl in a transaction?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I'm creating DDL for all of the objects in my db for propogation to the upper environments.  I want to ensure an all or nothing transaction including all database object creates/alters and data load inserts. Is it as simple as this or are there any caveats?

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

-- include create script generated from ssms

-- include insert data load scripts

COMMIT
```

I normally just use transactions for multi-table inserts etc.

Comment: why do u need begin and commit ?

Comment: https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
USE [DatabaseName]
GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION Tran1
    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT ...
        COMMIT TRANSACTION Tran1
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        -- ROLLBACK first.
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION Tran1
    END CATCH
GO
```

Be advised that, if this fails and any of the tables that have identities where data was inserted but subsequently rolled back, then the identity values will need to be RESEEDED. For some reason, the incrementing of Identity values occurs outside of transactions.

Comment: What would it roll back to, considering that concurrent transactions can also be incrementing this value, and committing their work? The last used identity value is nothing more than metadata.

Comment: The identity value does not get rolled back. You will need to manually roll it back yourself if needed by using the RESEED command.

Comment: Yes, obviously. My point was that you said 'for some reason'. The reason is because, in the event of ROLLBACK, the server has no way to roll back an IDENTITY column. I posed a question to you: in the presence of concurrent transactions that already committed, what would it roll back to? <- This was intended to provoke thought, not get an answer. The answer is "The server cannot roll back an IDENTITY "last used" value for this reason." The last used IDENTITY value has to be handled outside of the transaction, for common sense reasons.

Comment: As an aside, the rollback behavior of IDENTITY is irrelevant to the OP's question, because OP is also doing the DDL inside of the same transaction. So, those tables will be gone when the transaction rolls back, anyway.

Comment: I see what you are asking. One could get the max value of the current identity before the transaction and then reseed in the catch block with the max value.

Comment: That won't work. There may be concurrent transactions also 'taking' identity values, going well beyond whatever the 'max' value was at that time.

Comment: Yeah, I can see your point. That is a narrowly defined use case. Again, I was pointing this fact out to the OP in the event that it mattered.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you generally execute both DDL and DML within a transaction to ensure all-or-none. However, some DDL (e.g. `CREATE DATABASE`) cannot be executed in a transaction and others (e.g. `CREATE SCHEMA`) must be the only statement in a batch.

Barring those restrictions, you can use both transactions and structured error handling in your T-SQL script:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    -- include create script generated from ssms

    -- include insert data load scripts

    COMMIT;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK;
    THROW;
END;
```